# Why 'add' method doesn't work for mutableListOf()?

Tags: kotlin

I have my own converter from Strings to List

```
object TypeConverter {

    fun stringToListLong(text: String): List<Long> {
        val listLong = mutableListOf<Long>()
        val listString = text.split(",").map { it.trim() }
        listString.forEach {
            listLong.add(it.toLong())
        }
        return listLong
    }
}
```

Then when I try to use it like below it shows the error(Unresolved reference: add)

```
val someString = "something"
var ids = TypeConverter.stringToListLong(someString)
ids.add(some long value)
```

Why?

Comment: your function returns `List<Long>` witch is a base type that doesn't have `add()` methods.

Comment: Thx! Now I see that I did a mistake there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're returning a `List<>`, so `ids` is a `List<>`, therefore it does not have mutation operations. Make `stringToListLong` return `MutableList<Long>`.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much. I didn't notice that I made stringToListLong return immutable list.